# Running PHP from JavaScript asynchronously

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to get some suggestions when I write something in HTML form.

Hence,I call a JS function when `onkeypress` and `onkeyup` events are triggered on that form. In JS function I am using HTTP request object and fetching data from PHP file.

Here is a small snippet to give the idea of what I am doing.

HTML code :

```html
<form class="login" onsubmit="return isvalidated()" action="asd.php" method="post">
   <input id="userID" type="text" onkeypress="checkusername()" onkeyup="checkusername()" onblur="usercheckLv()" placeholder="username" name="user"><br><span class="errors" id="usererror"></span><br>
   <input id="passwordID" type="password" onblur="passwordcheckLv()" placeholder="password" name="password"><br><span class="errors" id="passworderror"></span><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

JavaScipt Code:

```js
function checkusername(){
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("usererror").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "xx.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
 }
}
```

PHP file xx.php :

```
<?php
    echo "fgfwegfdg";
?>
```

My HTML file is in a folder named `taxi` and `index.js` and `xx.php` are in `taxi/js` folder.

All other functions `usercheckLv()` `passwordcheckLv()` `isvalidated()` are there in `index.js` file and all those functions are working correctly. The`checkusername()` is being called (I had debug it).

But the inside function in `checkusername()` is not working.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Note: I am running the files through localhost in Ubuntu

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: No error in browser console. I would want "fgfwegfdg" to be writtern to usererror as soon as I hit a key in username. But this isn't happening

Comment: What is the location of **html** & **xx.php** file? Both file are in same or different folders?

Comment: If you go to http://localhost/xx.php you see your result ?

Comment: My HTML file is in a folder named taxi.  index.js and xx.php are in taxi/js folder.

Comment: I think your php file is not in the right place. And just to be sure, Apache (or equivalent) is running ? Can you access the file through your browser ?

Comment: Yeah I see "fgfwegfdg" writtern when I run localhost/taxi/js/xx.php

Comment: Update this code `xmlhttp.open("GET", "xx.php", true);` to `xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/taxi/js/xx.php", true);`

Comment: JS function checkusername() is called definitely(I had debug it).Moreover the PHP file is in same folder as JS file. I have already mentioned it before.

Comment: Move your PHP file to the same folder as HTML file, and check ?

Comment: Tried @Mateo ,no luck!

Comment: Tried @DevendraBhandari no luck!

Comment: Guys,atleast upvote the question if you can't give the solution. Others could see this question then!

Comment: No one can debug this more easily that you.  Use your browser console to investigate the http requests, are they triggering on every keypress of that input field?  Do they contain the expected send and receive data?  Use alerts in code to see if stuff is getting triggered, like your ajax response function.

Comment: @James : I have put a alert message outside the onreadystatechange function, it is showing alert message when I am pressing the key. But when I put alert in that function only , nothing happens!

Comment: I put open and send function above onreadystatechange, then when I press any key, it is going inside onreadystatechange but it is not going inside its "if" condition. Now any help!

Answer (score 0):

if the checkusername function is being called but not response whatsover, the problem must be from your Ajax calls then.

I recommend you look through each line of ur function code carefully as they are case sensitive, especially the xhttp part of it. Check w3school for the correct syntax.

Alternatively; use if(xhttp.statusText === 'OK') as supposed if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200). You can also add console.log() messages in ur code to know where the code breaks.

Hope this helps